# Is it possible to run single node instances of WSO2 API Manager in an active-passive deployment pattern

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

As per my current understanding and the documentation, the single node instances of API Manager v2.6.0 (All-in-one API Manager) can be set up to run in an active-active pattern. Is it not possible to run them in an active-passive pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. It's completely up to the loadbalancer to decide.